# Marathon instances are not running

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

Below is my tomcat.json file:

```
{
  "id":"tomcat-docker",
  "mem":512,
  "cpus":1.0,
  "instances":1,
  "container":{
    "type":"DOCKER",
    "docker":{
      "image":"tomcat:8.0",
      "network":"BRIDGE",
      "portMappings":[
        {
          "containerPort":8080,
          "hostPort":0,
          "servicePort":10000,
          "protocol":"tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "healthChecks":[
    {
      "protocol":"HTTP",
      "portIndex":0,
      "path":"/"
    }
  ]
}
```

While running the application using marathon, it's running and I am creating 1 instance of Tomcat which can be accessed from myhostname:31571. When I click on this instance it's showing:

> "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at hostname:31571"

Comment: If you don't have a DNS system, then you will not be able to resolve that hostname. A way around it is to use the --hostname mesos flag provided with the public ip of your slave. Or else, use a reverse proxy.